# Retrieve request data information's using JSR223 post processer in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am using the following payload as post request to one of my test servers, and I want to retrieve the size of the payload, uniquid from the payload. I am using JSR223 post processer for this any help to get these information

Sample Payload:

```
POST https://test.eventgrid.azure.net/api/events

POST data:
[
  {
    "subject": "audit",
    "id": "6aca5990-713b-47d1-be81-ed228bd81735",
    "eventType": "test.audit",
    "eventTime": "2020-08-31T05:02:02.462Z",
    "data": {
      "version": "1.0",
      "application": {
        "id": "PI0001",
        "name": "PLMAS",
        "component": {
          "id": "PLMAS01",
          "name": "SingleFileImporter",
          "type": "LogicApp"
        }
      },
      "audit": {
        "id": "168999807c4c46af908ce7a455a5e5eb",
        "timestamp": "2020-08-31T05:02:02.462Z",
        "type": "input",
        "entry": "File retrieved, validated and processed successfully",
        "message": {
          "headers": "J9SGinwTz0SSrEHrBrhMS3wquHlWu",
          "payload": "00=SfsDZ0LESTLZ6VpCmIEDT5nqOPqlwUJknCSIQuAIBM8wKj",
          "type": "csv",
          "protocol": ""
        },
        "keys": [
          {
            "name": "file-archive-location",
            "value": "Performance Test From Jmeter"
          }
        ]
      },
      "context": {
        "transactionId": "65174971-62d6-44da-9ecd-537b8d636464",
        "messageId": "04cb206c-25dd-4385-bed7-42f770c67cb8",
        "customerId": "FANSOI",
        "studyId": "FANSOI1234"
      }
    },
    "dataVersion": "1.0",
    "metadataVersion": "1"
  }
]
```

Is there any default method like `sampler.getUrl()` to get the request url and `sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue()` to get the request body.

Comment: what is uniqueid you mention ?

Comment: the  first `id` from the JSON payload is the `uniquid`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same functions but instead of `sampler` go for `ctx.getCurrentSampler()`, something like:

```
def data = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue()

def size = data.length()
def id = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(data)[0].id

log.info('Size: ' + size)
log.info('Id: ' + id)
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
import java.util.List;
def size = prev.getBodySizeAsLong() + prev.getHeadersSize();
List<String> list = com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read( prev.getQueryString(), "$..id");
String uniqueId = list.get(0).toString();
log.info("size:{}, uniqueId:{}", size, uniqueId);
```

Comment: Do I need to import anything here? because I am getting `2020-08-31 20:54:24,577 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[EventGridTest 1-2,6,main]
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: defaultReader
 at com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.JsonSmartJsonProvider.<init>(JsonSmartJsonProvider.java:39) ~[json-path-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
`